# Setting cookies for web view winjs

Tags: html, webview, microsoft-metro, winjs

So i am using x-ms-webview in my metro app (using HTML/JavaScript) and require to enable/set cookies. I have tried setting document.cookie field but no success. Whats is the correct way to do the same ?

Comment: I believe they operate in different security zones, so you cannot do that. You can't safely host a web page from a different zone and set cookies. The WebView is just an iframe. So, this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) applies.

Comment: The url i am navigating to is from my app data, so i don't think different security zone comes in picture here.

Comment: What's the `src` of the `x-ms-webview`?

Comment: i am using webview.navigate("ms-appdata:///local/filename")

Comment: I am not sure how much it helps U.
[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx ]
Look at the **7.How to clear the WebView cache**

Comment: You're trying to set a cookie for an entirely locally hosted web page?

Comment: @WiredPrairie yeah thats right

Comment: @kumar read the same before hosting not a solution to my issue. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Could you show the code you're using and where it's executing?

Comment: i am calling the following code in button's click event handler
var element = document.createElement('x-ms-webview');
element.id = "myWebView";                          element.navigate("ms-appdata:///local/folderName/index.html");

Answer (score 1):

```
var webview = element.querySelector("x-ms-webview");
var httpRequestMessage = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(
      Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.get,
      new Windows.Foundation.Uri("www.sample.com"));
// ... more settings

httpRequestMessage.headers.cookie.tryParseAdd("a=b;c=d;");

webview.navigateWithHttpRequestMessage(httpRequestMessage);
```

usually tryParseAdd(string) is enough, goto http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httprequestmessage.aspx
for more info.